# firestore.d.ts:11:64 - error TS2694: Namespace 'admin.firestore' has no exported member 'QueryDocumentSnapshot'

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, firebase-admin

all of a sudden I started getting error as below. I did not added any new libraries etc. and it was working fine yesterday.

```
11 export declare type QueryDocumentSnapshot = firebase.firestore.QueryDocumentSnapshot;
                                                                  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

src/index.ts:93:57 - error TS2345: Argument of type '(request: Request, response: Response<any>) => Promise<void | "" | Response<any>>' is not assignable to parameter of type '(req: Request, resp: Response<any>) => void | Promise<void>'.
  Type 'Promise<void | "" | Response<any>>' is not assignable to type 'void | Promise<void>'.
    Type 'Promise<void | "" | Response<any>>' is not assignable to type 'Promise<void>'.
      Type 'void | "" | Response<any>' is not assignable to type 'void'.
        Type '""' is not assignable to type 'void'.
```

my package.json looks like below

```
{
  "name": "functions",
  "scripts": {
    "lint": "tslint --project tsconfig.json",
    "build": "tsc",
    "serve": "npm run build && firebase serve --only functions",
    "shell": "npm run build && firebase functions:shell",
    "start": "npm run shell",
    "deploy": "firebase deploy --only functions",
    "logs": "firebase functions:log"
  },
  "main": "lib/index.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "@sendgrid/mail": "^6.3.1",
    "@types/node": "^12.12.8",
    "atob": "^2.1.2",
    "botbuilder": "^4.7.0",
    "btoa": "^1.2.1",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "firebase-admin": "^5.12.1",
    "firebase-functions": "^3.3.0",
    "newsapi": "^2.4.0",
    "nodemailer": "^6.4.2",
    "request": "^2.87.0",
    "request-promise-native": "^1.0.5"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "tslint": "^5.11.0",
    "typescript": "^3.7.2"
  },
  "private": true,
  "engines": {
    "node": "8"
  }
}
```

i am not using even firestore anywhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For now i had to downgrade firebase and that fixed it. sure that is not a solution but a workaround for now.